# How to use qooxdoo with MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, frameworks, qooxdoo

I have a work assignment, and I don't have any alternative; I have to use the [qooxdoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qooxdoo) framework.

How can I do a query with MySQL and PHP using this framework? In the examples present in the site, all tables use random values or JSON values, but in this case, I need PHP.

I know that I can't use PHP code inside a JavaScript file, so is Ajax the unique solution?

How I can solve that?

Answer (score 5):

You write a PHP [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) service which provides the data to your qooxdoo application. You can find more input on this in *[PHP RPC](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.3/pages/communication/rpc_php.html)* (qooxdoo documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create your own transport, for example, use AJAX to fetch JSONP.
See more info at http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.3/pages/communication/remote_io.html